# Django: issues migrating to custom user model

Tags: django, django-models, django-custom-user

I've been writing a Django webapp without much concern for my User model- the provided model has been good, but I've realized that I'd like to be able to customize it somehow.

Starting from scratch with a custom user model looks pretty straightforward, but migrating to one while keeping existing users is a bit trickier, and has been giving me a lot of issues. I found [this guide](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django_custom_user_migration) that uses a special package and has step-by-step instructions for my exact situation (Django 1.8, Python 3.4).

One of the prep steps is

*You must have ensured that everywhere in your project (including 3rd party libraries) you are using AUTH_USER_MODEL and django.contrib.auth.get_user_model() rather than "auth.User" and django.contrib.auth.models.User.*

My project isn't super complex- the only references to the User model are in ForeignKeys as well as a couple lines that get User objects.

Where should I use django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()? My impression is that ForeignKeys need to use settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL and any runtime operation (e.g. `obj = User.objects.get(<criteria>)` would set `User` with `get_user_model()`. Is that correct?

I currently have my AUTH_USER_MODEL setting like:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = User
```

as an intermediate step, with an import of `django.contrib.auth.models.User` at the top of `settings.py`.

I tried to switch my models to use the setting:

```
class League(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

However when I start the server, I keep getting an error about `settings.py`

```
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

What am I doing wrong here? The SECRET_KEY setting isn't empty, so I'm thinking there's a different error in the settings.

Comment: You can't import models inside settings. That's what's causing the strange secret key error. The `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting should be a string, like `'auth.user'`.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I'll try that when I get back home

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little unclear where you're at right now in the switch from the default to your custom user, but like the docs say [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user), your `AUTH_USER_MODEL` should be set like:

`AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'`

As a string, not importing the model directly.  `'auth.User'` is the default setting, so if you want to use the default user in your code just set it like that, and when you're ready to switch it over change it to whatever app name and model so: `'my_app.CustomUser'`

You're getting the `SECRET_KEY` error because you're trying to import django.contrib.auth.models.User at the top of settings.py., and so it's importing other parts of the django library before the settings file, but the settings file is supposed to be loaded first.

Comment: Much appreciated- I've been reading those pages, but thought I was just missing something with respect to `get_user_model()`. I'm still very early in the switch- I actually tried this a while ago and ran into problems, so I think I need to zero out my previous `accounts` app to even follow the directions on the page I linked in the question.